# How can I install Paint.NET on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, paint.net

I previously installed Paint.NET and removed it (imprudently, I might add) by deleting its program files. Now when I try to reinstall it via the executable file found within the zip file [here](http://www.dotpdn.com/files/Paint.NET.3.5.10.Install.zip) it says an error occurred during installation (after it had at least attempted to remove the previous installation).

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: do you have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 activated in "Turn Features on or off"?

Comment: It says error 1603 whatever that means

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have no idea, I am no programmer.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off. The error is a generic code. Look in the temp folder if you can find a log file. Upload this log.

Comment: @magicandre1981 as I just told you I am no programmer I am only an average user when it comes to PCs if you want me to do something you have to tell me step by step of what to do. As for whether it's on or off the box next to the folder titled, "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" is coloured but the contents of this folder aren't ticked.

Comment: this has nothing to do with being a programmer. Check the .net 3.5.1 checkbox and click ok. I posted a guide which shows you how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is properly remove the failed install using a tool like Revo Uninstaller.  Once that is completed you have a much better chance of being able to perform a fresh install.

If you have trouble with Revo it's well worth trying the[Program Install and Uninstall Fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall).

Comment: When I tried to uninstall Paint.NET with this tool it gave me the error: `There is a problem with this Windows Installer package A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor`

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Install and Uninstall Utility?

Comment: Yeah I have but I found if I ignored the error I received it removed the program no problem

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.msigeek.com/715/how-to-troubleshoot-the-error-1603-fatal-error-during-installation) your `error 1603` case falls into `The setup was corrupted after installation and, therefore, fails with this error during un-installation.` category. As suggests the page you should proceed with `Microsoft Windows Installer CleanUp` utility,  however it's obsolete as of 2010.

Instead you sould use [Microsoft Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/). Download and run the utility, select `Problem with Uninstall`, and remove Paint.NET with it.

After that it most propably will install fine.